# Interface to Ethernet to USB bridge (LAN7800)

Tags: microcontroller, switches, ethernet, microchip

I have a design that requires interfacing LAN7800 chip (Ethernet to USB bridge) to a microcontroller on the same PCB.

I am using SAME54 microcontroller. This is then connected to one of KS8995 (Ethernet switch) ports via MII interface.

From here I intend on using one of the switch's ports to interface to LAN7800. Only interested in 100Mb connection, not 1Gig.

All the IC's are on the same PCB. Am I correct in assuming that, in order to properly interface SAME54 to LAN7800 I need to follow this chain:

SAME54 -> [MII] -> KS8995 -> [Transformer] -> LAN7800

The reason for asking is that for applications where LAN7800 is on a separate board, I expect the chain to be as such:

SAME54 -> [MII] -> KS8995 -> [Transformer/RJ45] -> [Twisted Pair] -> [Transformer/RJ45] -> LAN7800.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is your question? EMI concerns, etc.

Comment: @ErikFriesen Just a general is this correct for functionality? i.e. is simply having a standard Ethernet transformer between the switch and the bridge is enough the meet 100Mb Ethernet termination requirements. Just seems like I have an unusual use-case and "feels" it wrong, that there should be more to it. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Depends what the USB interface is connected to. Why don't you connect the USB straight to the micro?

Comment: @Finbarr The intention for USB is to be connect to a PC/laptop. In this case, the microcontroller is responsible for a lot of data from different subsystems. From what I can tell, SAM5 provides native USB interface that can only do 12Mb. This is too low. The intention is to use bridge/switch to get 100Mb via MII out to USB.